# code won't run..can't run the bool function

Tags: c++, class, boolean

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class sekuence
{
  public:

  sekuence() {
    string emra[5][20];
    int m=0;
  }

void shto (){
    int i;
    int j;
    char temp[20];
    cout << "=============================="<<endl
         << "Shkruani emrat qe doni te shtoni ne vektor"<<endl;
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
        cin >> emra[i];
        m++;
    }
    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for( j=1; j<5; j++){
            if(strcmp(emra[j-1],emra[j]) > 0) {
                strcpy(temp,emra[j-1]);
                strcpy(emra[j-1],emra[j]);
                strcpy(emra[j],temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
void print(){
    for(int i=0; i<5 ; i++){
        cout<<endl<<emra[i];
    }
    cout <<m;
}  

bool kerko (const char *gjej)
{
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(emra[i],gjej) == 0 )
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

int n (){return m;}

private:
    int m;
    char emra[5][20];
};




int main()
{   char* gjej;
    int x;
    sekuence d;

do{
cout<<endl << " =========================" << endl;
cout<<"1 - Funksioni i shtimit"   <<endl;
cout<<"2 - Funksioni i afishimit" <<endl;
cout<<"3 - Funksioni i kerkimit"  <<endl;
cout<<"4 - Funksioni i fshirjes"  <<endl;
cout<<"5 - Dalje nga programi"    <<endl<<endl;
cout<<"====================================" <<endl;
cin >> x;
switch (x)
{
case 1:
    d.shto();
    break;
case 2:
    d.print();
    break;
case 3:
    cout<<"==================================" <<endl
    << "Shkruani emrin qe doni te kerkoni"<<endl;
    cin >> gjej;
    d.kerko(gjej);
    break;
case 4:
    break;
case 5:
    cout << "Dalje nga Programi" <<endl;
    exit (0);
default:
    cout <<"Zgjedhje e gabuar";
    return 0;
}}
while (x != 5);
    return 0;

}
```

Everytime I try to run the bool function I get an error..i don't what to do.
when i try to enter the nam i want to fine the function bool kerko() and quit the prog. and want find the char i want to find it opens the visual studio debugger.

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: What error? It's important to include that error in your post. See [ask].

Comment: You do know that you are declaring *local* variables in the constructor, that will shadow the private member variables?

Comment: `bool kerko (const char *gjej)` has a major logic problem.  No matter what you're trying to do, this function is written incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access gjej (char*) but no memory allocated to it. Try allocating some memory using `new`

```
char* gjej = NULL;
gjej = new char[NumberOfChars];
```

Edit: used `new` instead of `malloc` now..

`std::string` would be even nicer..

Comment: Using `neẁ` would probably better since is after all a C++ program.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes.. in fact I would prefer std::string :) Edited now :)

Comment: how should i use the string way

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I got an error when I tried that. Said `undeclared identifier: neẁ`. Can you help?

Comment: @user3105161 Follow this sample.. http://www.digitalmars.com/archives/cplusplus/2241.html And make sure you google it before asking question..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Seems you computer is broken.. did you tried restart :P

Answer (score 0):

According to your indentation of the `kerko` function, one of the `return` statements should be moved out of the `for` loop:

```
bool kerko (const char *gjej)
{
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(emra[i],gjej) == 0 )
            return true;
    }
    //*** Note the new location.
        return false;
}
```

The layout you have makes the `bool` function always return before the 2nd iteration of the loop.